# How do I trigger an event when a new email is received in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I trigger an event when a new email is received in Outlook?

I can't get the initialization to work in Outlook 2013 when following [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qcftHAWnZI).

In the code below, `Debug.Print` does not print and it doesn't seem to run. I get no feedback from the system so I'm having trouble troubleshooting.

```vb
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

'On start up
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

Debug.Print "Application_Startup trigerred " & Now()

End Sub

'New email recieved
Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

Dim my_olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set my_olMail = item
        
        Debug.Print my_olMail.Subject
        Debug.Print my_olMail.Attachments.Count
        Debug.Print my_olMail.SenderEmailAddress
        
    Set my_olMail = Nothing
    
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is save the changes and restart Outlook.